# Multiple Lines in the Same Plot in R

Tags: r, plot, lines

Sorry if this is a repeat question but I couldn't figure it out from the other posts as I'm still learning R. I want to place the 3 stochastic lines on the plot but when I run my code it only plots the 3rd line on the original graph.

My code......

```
r=0.19
N=rep(0,50)
N[1]=13
K=130
for(t in 1:50){
N[t+1]= N[t] + N[t]*r*(1-(N[t]/K))}
plot(1:51, N, type="l", lwd=3, xlab="Time")

K=130
Ns=rep(0,50)
Ns[1]=13
for(t in 1:50){
r=rnorm(1, .19, 0.13)
Ns[t+1]= Ns[t] + Ns[t]*r*(1-(Ns[t]/K))}
plot(1:51, N, type="l", lwd=3, xlab="Time")
lines(1:51, Ns, lwd=3, col='blue')
lines(1:51, Ns, lwd=3, col='green')
lines(1:51, Ns, lwd=3, col='red')
```

Comment: You are plotting three same lines on top of each other - what else do you expect to see?

Comment: I thought that since it was stochastic it would generate 3 different lines since if I did just the first one it is different everytime I run it.

Comment: Thanks fixed it by making it Ns1, Ns2, and Ns3. I figured it was a simple fix but I was just introduced to this last week and hadn't looked at it again until today.

Comment: Please accept the answer ('tick' on the left) if you are satisfied with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not regenerating your random parameter, so all your lines use the same `Ns`. That is, they are drown on top of each other and you see only one of them.